# Проблема со строками: выдает ошибку "buffer is too small"

Tags: c, строки

Дело в том что я ввожу n-ое число строк типа: фамилия дата рождения город и программа должна вывести фамилию возраст  город.Вопрос в том что как разбить строку что бы дату возраст можно было посчитать!

```
#define M 30
#define N 100

int main()
{
    char s[N], s2[N],s3[N], dtm[N];
    char array[M][N], n;
    int x, i;
    for (n = 0; n < M && s[0] != '\n'; ++n)
    {
        fgets(s, N, stdin);
        strcpy_s(dtm, s);
        sscanf_s(dtm, "%100s %d %100s", s2,100, &x, s3,100);
        x = 2017 - x;
        strcpy_s(array[n], dtm);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", );
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

В одной строке все задаем например (`Иванов 1988 Иваново`).

Comment: Посмотрите на sscanf для чтения данных (в частности даты) из строки, а затем вычитайте эту дату из текущей (получите возраст)

Comment: Не совсем понял, можно поподробней?

Comment: Для "поподробней" надо знать формат данных (особенно даты) в строке.

Comment: в Одной строке все задаем например (Иванов 1988 Иваново)

Comment: Ну вы хоть документацию по `sscanf` откройте - там всё написано.

Comment: Читайте man-ы [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf), [time](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time), [localtime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) (что останется непонятно, спрашивайте)

Comment: А понял,спасибо

Comment: исправил но выдает ошибку "buffer is too small" что не так?

Comment: я читал о sscanf и там в примерах уже существующая строка рассматривается,а можете ли вы мне показать как работать со строками которые я сам ввожу

Comment: У вас ни одна функция, которая может возвратить код ошибки, не проверяется. А так у вас должно быть условно `%100s` в параметрах.

Comment: Поправил код и все ровно после ввода первой строки получаю прекращение программы

Comment: Посомтрите я исправил как вывести теперь возраст и все остольное?